# Out of Office / Case Routing

Tags: process-builder, case, queue, email2case

Chatter has an option to set "Out of Office" with dates and a message. I haven't found this data on an object. I have users that are assigned cases going out of office but their case load needs to be assigned to a Queue when this happens. Does anyone know if it is possible to target this to route cases to a queue instead of the user when out of office. I can't seem to find the field anywhere. When out of office is checked and unchecked does it toggle anything? Any info would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE, Please Edit your question and add what you have tried for this requirement. Here we doesn't provide any full solution. We can help to overcome any specific issue once you tried something and stuck in anywhere. as per you're given question. it's able to done by any automation like flow or apex also. So please try and get back here (if you stuck) :)

Comment: Hey there. I totally understand the need to try things. The issue is that I cannot find where that data lives. If I knew anything related to "Out of Office" and if those fields existed I feel confident in finding a way to create that automation via flow, PB, or Apex. It is available on the Chatter Page. Is there a Chatter Object?

Comment: I think these 2 links are help you 1) https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/196320/chatter-out-of-office-winter-18 and 2) https://www.salesforcecodecrack.com/2019/06/how-to-set-out-of-office-messag.html